# Cannot find a forked and pulled repository on my local machine

Tags: git, gitlab

I forked and pulled a repo from my professor using the `git clone` http method in GitLab. I am on a Windows machine and am using `cygwin` as my console.  The console shows the assignment files in directory when I navigate there and verify however, according to the path shown in `cygwin` the files are not there on my local computer. Any ideas on what may have happened?

Comment: cywgin would present you with a unix-like path which actually doesn't have any reference to your actual Windows drive structure yes? Perhaps the best bet is to "Find" in Windows

Comment: @RobbieAverill that's correct, the two OS paths styles are very different. But Cygwin does have a handy way to help out with this sort of thing--see my answer, below.

Comment: It gave me a new directory to look in but still wasn't there: $ cygpath -w /abs/hunter/dev/assignment1 ----- >  C:\cygwin64\abs\hunter\dev\assignment1

Comment: OK.  I found it...sorry!  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Cygwin prompt, type `pwd` to figure out where you are (this is a unix path). Then type `cygpath -w /abs/path/to/yourFiles` and this should give you the windows style path you can use to find the files locally from your C drive.